# Key Value in combobox lwuit?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-list, lwuit-combobox

I want to store and retrieve a key value associated with the comboBox. I have used only 
getSelectedIndex() and getSelectedItem(). This will not help my purpose as I have to get a unique key value assocaiated with the item.

Example Scenario :

India - 10, China - 15, Russia - 18.  Here if 'India' is the comboBox item then '10' is its key. Likewise, 15 for china and 18 for Russia.

When India is selected I need to get the value as 10, if china 15, if Russia 18.

How can I achieve this in Lwuit 1.5. could you guys guide me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must map the values with the items in the `ComboBox`.

You can do this in some different ways.

You can do it with a `Hashtable` for example. You will need to make the proper castings to get the value in the data type what you want.

```
    ComboBox combo;

    //Here create the hash
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    h.put("India", "10");
    h.put("China", "15");
    h.put("Russia", "18");

    //create the combo
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.addElement("India");
    v.addElement("China");
    v.addElement("Russia");
    combo = new ComboBox(v);
    combo.addActionListerner(new ActionListener ae){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
             String selected = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
             //get the value
             String value = (String) h.get(selected);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks jmunoz, just what I was looking for